# Java Regex Extraction

Tags: java, extract

I have a string

```
I #have# #a# #string#
```

I have the regex `#[^#]+#` that should give strings between hash marks in this string.

I need to declare

```
String y = {first word surrounded by hashmarks in sentence}
```

Help me change the above pseudo-code into real code, please.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: What pseudo-code? I only see requirements here.

Comment: You have to put more effort before asking a question and actually do sth by yourself first so that you can paste your code here.

Comment: thanks, but read through that already in my quest and didn't glean from it what i apparently should have.

Comment: First go through this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html and go back to us after you do. Of course then you may know the answer but if you do not we'll help you.

Comment: I read through that, too, just now, and couldn't find a method that captures something.  I found ones that give you the index of a pattern instance, replace the first instance, but I didn't see one that "copies" and "pulls out" the text inside the regex pattern used.

Comment: Have you read ["Java - Extract strings with Regex"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224934/java-extract-strings-with-regex?rq=1) SO post?

Comment: Pattern P = Pattern.compile(#[^#]+#),  Matcher m = p.matcher(stri);??

Comment: That post and another one lead me to the guess above: does it look like I'm on the right track?

Comment: Why use a regex at all? A simple replacement of '#' with '' does the trick.

Comment: I'm not interested in turning the words into strings as much as I am interested in having a named string that I can then pass to another method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#([^#]+)#");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("I #have# #a# #string#");
    while(matcher.find()){
        String y = matcher.group(1);
        // do something with y
    }
```

Explanation:

The parenthesis around `[^#]+` allow to capture the content between them, and access it later by calling `group(1)` on the `matcher`. The `1` means first parenthesis group (in our example there is only one anyway).

The loop might be optional in your case. It iterates on all the words between `#` found in the string. If you only want the first one just call `matcher.find()` once with no loop.

Comment: Can you explain this code?

Comment: specifically, does matcher.group(1) refer to the first instance of the matcher?

Comment: Thanks, wouldn't the match's number be 0, though?

Comment: No, 0 is a special index returning the whole pattern, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(int)