# Extract only values from string tags

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to extract values from a given string which could contain many tags with that pattern e.g

```
<element1>content1</element1><element2>content2</element2><element3>content3</element3>... and so on.
```

Currently this is a code with a regexp I'm using.

```java
String tempString = "<element1>content1</element1><element2>content2</element2>";
String[] tempArray = tempString.split("(<\\w+>)|(</\\w+>)");

for (String item : tempArray) {
    System.out.println("Item: " + item);
}
```

The result I expect is:

```
Item: content1
Item: content2

etc...
```

Instead of this I receive:

```
Item: 
Item: content1
Item:
Item: content2
```

I would like to get rid of these empty elements using only one-liner - **one magic** regexp. I mean - on a given string I apply this expression as a one line and magically I receive my expected values in an array - without further processing or grouping.
Is it even possible to achieve?

Comment: I suggest reading this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your existing code snippet you can apply the following code to achieve it, using some regex.
Have a look at the code below

Import the regex util

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

String pattern = "\\w+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
String tempString =
  "<element1>content1</element1><element2>content2</element2>";
String[] tempArray = tempString.split ("(<\\w+>)|(</\\w+>)");
for (String item:tempArray)
  {
      Matcher matcher = r.matcher(item);
      //check if the pattern matches 
      if(matcher.matches()){
          System.out.println ("Item: " + item);
      }
  }
```

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: I think no need of Regex, here by applying check for non empty strings will work.

Comment: yes that would also do.but you mentioned regex, so i used regex in the example.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to apply a "matcher" functionality within the given regex?
I would like to have just expression which returns expected values - without further lines of code (matcher, grouping).

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of capture group backreferences and lazy quantifiers to dynamically get all of the content:

```
<(element\d+)>(.*?)<\/\1>
```

- `<(element\d+)>` - find a tag named "element" followed by at least one digit and it into `$1` (ex. `element1`)
- `(.*?)` - lazily capture everything into `$2` until the next regex instruction succeeds
- `<\/\1>` - use `\1` to reference what we caught in `$1` and match it as a closing tag

and `$2` will contain:

```
content1
content2
content3
```

https://regex101.com/r/NAImHv/1/

You can use [Java - Extract strings with Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1224934/2191572) to fit my regex into Java code.

---

**Disclaimer:** Regex is absolutely the wrong tool for this and you should definitely look into XPath but this is a quick n' dirty solution if you are okay with getting tripped up by edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok using streams, you can use your regex and just filter out the empty ones:

```
String tempString = "<element1>content1</element1><element2>content2</element2>";
String[] tempArray = Pattern.compile("(<\\w+>)|(</\\w+>)").splitAsStream(tempString)
                            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tempArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Xpath:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class Extract {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, XPathExpressionException {
        // Q 57876359

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        String xml = new String("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                "<elements>\r\n" + 
                "   <element1>content1</element1>\r\n" + 
                "   <element2>content2</element2>\r\n" + 
                "   <element3>content3</element3>\r\n" + 
                "</elements>");
        InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
        Document doc = builder.parse(is);   
        XPathFactory xpathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xpathfactory.newXPath();

        int nodes = doc.getChildNodes().getLength();    

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getChildNodes();    
        //To get <elements> root node
        Node firstNode = nodeList.item(0);

        //To get childs element0...elementN
        NodeList elementNodes = firstNode.getChildNodes();

        //Last node is a text node
        Node lastInnerNode = elementNodes.item(elementNodes.getLength()-2);

        //To extract index of last tag
        String lastInnerNodeName = lastInnerNode.getNodeName(); 
        int lastNodeIndex =  Integer.parseInt(lastInnerNodeName.substring(lastInnerNodeName.length()-1, lastInnerNodeName.length()));

        XPathExpression xpathexpression;

        //To extract every content
        for (int i = 1; i <= lastNodeIndex; i++) {
            xpathexpression = xpath.compile("//element"+i+"/text()");
            Object result = xpathexpression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
            String texto = (String) result;
            System.out.println("Item: "+texto);
        }
  }
```