# Get a specific data values from a string in Java (String without comma)

Tags: java, string

I want to get the value from a string.

I have a string value like this:

```
String myData= "Number: 34678 Type: Internal Qty: 34";
```

How can I get the Number, Type, Qty values separately?

Give me any suggestion on this.

**Input:**

```
String myData= "Number: 34678 Type: Internal Qty: 34";
```

**Output:**

```
Number value is 34678 
Type values is Internal 
Qty value is 34
```

Comment: You could use a regex to parse the string.

Comment: I don't have any idea about regex. Do you give any example for regex?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the string is always formatted like that. I.e., `n` attribute names each followed by a value that does not contain spaces. In other words, the `2n` entities are separated from each other by 1 or more spaces.

If so, try this:

```
String[] parts;
int      limit;
int      counter;
String   name;
String   value;
parts = myData.split("[ ]+");
limit = (parts.length / 2) * 2; // Make sure an even number of elements is considered
for (counter = 0; counter < limit; counter += 2)
{
  name = parts[counter].replace(":", "");
  value = parts[counter + 1];
  System.out.println(name + " value is " + value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks your code is helpful. But I am facing some errors arrayindexofbound. My input is,
String mydata = "Number: 332W3314-64 Type: Internal Qty: 3 Exact

Comment: Updated the answer so it considers only the actual pairs of name/value

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do this cleanly:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Number: (\\d*) Type: (.*) Qty: (\\d*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myData);
m.find()
```

So you'll get the number with `m.group(1)`, the Type `m.group(2)` and the Qty  `m.group(3)`.

I assume you accept a limited number of types. So you can change the regex to match only if the type is correct, for eg. either Internal or External: `"Number: (\\d*) Type: (Internal|External) Qty: (\\d*)"`

Here's [a nice explanation of how this works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1224987/2743585)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.  It looks for a word following by a colon followed by zero or more spaces followed by another word.  This works regardless of the order or names of the fields.

```java
      String myData = "Number: 34678 Type: Internal Qty: 34";
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\S+):\\s*(\\S+)").matcher(myData);
      while (m.find()) {
         System.out.println(m.group(1) + " value is " + m.group(2));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print them with fixed pattern of input data, a simplest way is shown as follows: (Just for fun!)

```
System.out.print(myData.replace(" Type", "\nType")
            .replace(" Qty", "\nQty")
            .replace(":", " value is"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This Should work

```
    String replace = val.replace(": ", "|");

    StringBuilder number = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder type = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder qty = new StringBuilder();
    String[] getValues = replace.split(" ");
    int i=0;
    while(i<getValues.length-1){
        String[] splitNumebr = getValues[i].split("\\|");
        number.append(splitNumebr[1]);
        String[] splitType = getValues[i+=1].split("\\|");
        type.append(splitType[1]);
        String[] splitQty = getValues[i+=1].split("\\|");
        qty.append(splitQty[1]);
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Number value is %s",number.toString()));
    System.out.println(String.format("Type value is %s",type.toString()));
    System.out.println(String.format("Qty value is %s",qty.toString()));

}
```

**Output**
Number value is 34678
Type value is Internal
Qty value is 34